# Code sample loops indefinitely when using BigIntegers, but works with integers

Tags: java, biginteger

My actual condition in integers is

```
int d = 1;

while(true)
{
  if(((e*d)%f)==1)
  {
    break;
  }
  else 
    d++;
}
```

I have written this condition in BigInteger as

```
while(true)
{
  if(((e.multiply(d)).mod(f)).equals(1))
  {
    break;
  }
  else 
    d=d.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

When I execute the above code in BigInteger, it executes infinitely. But, when I execute the code in integers, it executes perfectly and comes out of the loop. Please tell me what the error is.

Comment: It would be helpful if you defined `e` and `f` in your example code.

Comment: And the initial definition of `d` for the `BigInteger` example. Is it `BigInteger d = BigInteger.ONE`?

Comment: `1` is an `int` or `Integer` but it is never equal to a BigInteger as this is a different type.

Comment: You can optimise e * d % f as `(e % f) * (d % f) % f`  The significance of this is that you can make the expressions smaller and you can be assured that you only need to consider `d` to `d + f - 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(((e.multiply(d)).mod(f)).equals(1))
```

You can't do an equals comparison with a `BigInteger` and an autoboxed `Integer`.

You need to do:

```
if(((e.multiply(d)).mod(f)).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
```